# Calculating 95th percentile with awk

Tags: awk

I'm new in awk scripting and would like to have some help in calculating 95th percentile value for a file that consist of this data:

```
0.0001357
0.000112
0.000062
0.000054
0.000127
0.000114
0.000136
```

I tried:

```
cat filename.txt | sort -n |
awk 'BEGIN{c=0} {total[c]=$1; c++;} END{print total[int(NR*0.95-0.5)]}'
```

but I dont seem to get the correct value when I compare it to excel.

Comment: What is your code's answer and what is excel's answer?

Comment: Does your input file really have blank lines between each data line?

Comment: Excel answer is 0,000991.

No, the input file does not have blank lines between each data line.

Comment: Then why put them in your sample data? I edited it to remove the blank lines now.

Comment: 0.000991 isn't one of your input values so Excel is wrong.

Answer (score 13):

I am not sure if Excel does some kind of weighted percentile, but if you actually want one of the numbers that was in your original set, then your method should work correctly for rounding.

You can simplify a little bit like this, but it's the same thing.

```
sort -n input.txt  | awk '{all[NR] = $0} END{print all[int(NR*0.95 - 0.5)]}'
```

Comment: In the original script the array started at zero, yours starts at 1. idk which is correct.

Comment: @EdMorton, It depends on your definition of `0th` percentile. :) I'm going to bunt on that and say that for large enough input the difference is not meaningful.

Comment: why the `-0.5`? `int(NR*0.95)` should be enough no?

Comment: `-0.5` appears to be to "force round down" (if that's what you want...)

Answer (score 2):

Following the calculation suggested [here](http://knowledgebase.solarwinds.com/kb/questions/403/How+is+the+95th+percentile+line+calculated%3F), you can do this:

```
sort file -n | awk 'BEGIN{c=0} length($0){a[c]=$0;c++}END{p5=(c/100*5); p5=p5%1?int(p5)+1:p5; print a[c-p5-1]}'
```

Output for given input:

```
sort file -n | awk 'BEGIN{c=0} length($0){a[c]=$0;c++}END{p5=(c/100*5); p5=p5%1?int(p5)+1:p5; print a[c-p5-1]}'
0.0001357
```

Explanation:

1. Sort the file numerically
2. drop the top 5%
3. pick the next value

PS. The statement `p5=p5%1?int(p5)+1:p5` is doing  a `ceil`  operation available in many languages.

Comment: Small correction, the first value is not 0,0001357 correct value is 0,001357. I dont have any blank lines in between my rows.

Excel gives me 0,000991 but my awk script gives me 0,001357 (same as the value in the first row).

Comment: Did you provide the same values for excel and for awk? if so excel is wrong as this value does not exist, 95th percentile does not change the samples.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, there is also  solution, inspired by merlin2011 answer, that prints several desired percentiles:

```
# get amount of values
num="$(wc -l input.txt | cut -f1 -d' ')";
# sort values
sort -n input.txt > temp && mv temp input.txt
# print the desired percentiles
for p in 50 70 80 90 92 95 99 100; do 
  printf "%3s%%: %-5.5sms\n" "$p" "$(head input.txt -n "$((num / 100 * $p))" | tail -n1)";
done
```

**Update**: I messed it up. Bash math can't handle floating numbers, even not if used during a "single expression". That only works for files with `100*(N>0)` values. So either `bc` or `awk` is required to do the math.

In case you have an "odd" amount of values, you should replace `"$((num / 100 * $p))"` with `"$(awk "BEGIN {print int($num/100*$p)}")"` in the code above.

Finally `awk` is part of that answer. ;)