# Calculate Percentile(s) in Bash

Tags: bash, unix, awk, statistics

I am trying to calculate a range of percentiles (5th-99th) in `Bash` for a text file that contains 5 values, one per line.

**Input**

```
34.5
32.2
33.7
30.4
31.8
```

**Attempted Code**

```
awk '{s[NR-1]=$1} END{print s[int(0.05-0.99)]}' input
```

**Expected Output**

```
99th    34.5
97th    34.4
95th    34.3
90th    34.2
80th    33.9
70th    33.4
60th    32.8
50th    32.2
40th    32.0
30th    31.9
20th    31.5
10th    31.0
5th     30.7
```

Comment: Please post expected output in your question too.

Comment: Please share what you have already done. Also, please post output in text format. not an image

Comment: Hi @dash-o, I have already included my attempt in the "Attempted Code" section of my question. I have also edited my Expected Output to be in text format instead of an image.

Comment: @arnpry, Please see this thread https://stackoverflow.com/q/24707705/5866580 if this helps you?

Comment: What you posted is an awk script, not a bash script. You're calculating percentiles in awk, not in bash.

Comment: Hi @EdMorton, I'm running the `awk` script in Bash script, as well as passing my text file to my awk script

Comment: It doesn't matter. You could be running it in ksh, dash, Windows, whatever. What you're trying to do has nothing to do with bash and the solution will have nothing to do with bash. Mentioning bash in this question is as useful as mentioning the brand of PC you're running on. If in your question you provide the algorithm you want to use to calculate the percentiles I expect someone can help you write that in awk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For calculation of percentile based on 5 values, one need to create a mapping between percentiles, and to interpolate between them. A process called 'Piecewise Linear function' (a.k.a. `pwlf`).

F(100) = 34.5
F(75) = 33.7
F(50) = 32.2
F(25) = 31.8
F(0) = 30.4

Mapping of any other x in the range 0..100, require linear interpolation betweeh F(L), and F(H) - where L is the highest value >= x, and H=L+1.

```
awk '
#! /bin/env awk
  # PWLF Interpolation function, take a value, and two arrays for X & Y
function pwlf(x, px, py) {
  # Shortcut to calculate low index of X, >= p
  p_l = 1+int(x/25)
  p_h = p_l+1
  x_l = px[p_l]
  x_h = px[p_h]
  y_l = py[p_l]
  y_h = py[p_h]
#print "X=", x, p_l, p_h, x_l, x_h, y_l, y_h
  return y_l+(y_h-y_l)*(x-x_l)/(x_h-x_l)
}

  # Read f Input in yy array, setup xx
{ yy[n*25] = $1  ; n++ }

  # Print the table
END {
  # Sort values of yy
  ny = asort(yy) ;
  # Create xx array 0, 25, ..., 100
  for (i=1 ; i<=ny ; i++) xx[i]=25*(i-1)

  # Prepare list of requested results
  ns = split("99 97 95 90 80 70 60 50 40 30 20 10 5", pv)
  for (i=1 ; i<=ns ; i++) printf "%dth %.1f\n",  pv[i], pwlf(pv[i], xx, yy) ;
}
' input
```

Technically a `bash` script, but based on comments to OP, better to place the whole think into script.awk, and execute as one lines. Solution has the '#!' to invoke awk script.

```
/path/to/script.awk < input
```

Comment: wrt `Technically a bash script` - there is no part of that script that's bash. I'm just trying to make the point because so many people confuse awk with shell. The attempted shebang is doing nothing btw, it's just a comment inside the awk script.

Comment: Can you provide the `Bash`-only script?

Comment: @arnpry the original post is technically a bash solution. Having a 'pure-bash' solution is very difficult, bash support of floating point calculations is non-existent.

Comment: @EdMorton Technically, this is executed via bash, using bash quoting to pass multi-line string to awk as a program. I'm assuming this is part of a large task implemented in bash. I agree this should be classified better classified as awk-solution, given no dependency on bash features (can be invoked from any program: perl, python, c, or even another awk) - as  described at the bottom of the answer

Comment: That quoting would work in any shell or any other environment that allows for passing a single-quoted scripts to the tool that interprets it, there is nothing about your answer that requires bash. Also, again, the `#!` is just a comment inside the awk script, it does nothing functionally.

Comment: Where does the value 25 come from? I am trying to understand this to generalise it for longer lists than 5 values.

Comment: It is 100/(n-1), n is the number of points, 5 for the specific problem.

Comment: I tested this script against a list from 1 to 100 and it didn't give expected results: 
>> for ((i=1;i<100;i++)); do     echo $i; done | awk 'the script above with the pecentiles below'

results>> 
99th 5.0
95th 4.8
75th 4.0
50th 3.0